# how do Insert "#" in a c# string variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, escaping

Does anybody know how to insert "#" in a c# string variable? 
Is there any escape sequence for this kind of thing? 
for e.g.

```
string myString = "<li><a href="#1">Image 1</a><li>";
```

Comment: The `#` isn't a problem.  You need to escape the `"`

Comment: why don't you use the `'` character instead of `"` then no escaping needed

Comment: Thanks paddy. You were right # isn't the problem. I escaped the " and it works fine now. How do mark this as an answer and close this question?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
string myString = "<li><a href=\"#1\">Image 1</a><li>";
```

You have to escape the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
string myString = @"<li><a href=""#1\"">Image 1</a><li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string myString = "<li><a href='#1'>Image 1</a><li>";
```

It's better to use single quotes in attributes inside a c# string to avoid the escaping

Comment: Using the literal operator IMO is preferable, for readability, to escaping characters.

Answer (score -1):

Paddy was right. There was no need to escape [#]. I only had to escape ["]. It works fine now. Thanks Paddy and everyone else who responded.